# .htaccess to redirect subdirectory path name and mask with custom name

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-masking

I have a sub-directory named **CMS** {example.com/cms}. I need to redirect it to **example.com/blog** and mask that with the name blog. While doing this **example.com/cms/page1** should also redirect and mask with **example.com/blog/page1**. I need .htaccess code that do this. I have tried all codes available, nothing works.

the code i tried was

> RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /cms/$1 [L,NC]

Comment: Can you show an example code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in **your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^cms(/.*)?$ blog$1 [L,NC]
```